# Code that generates a random 10 digit filename and creates the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I tried using:

```
import random
filenamemaker = random.randint(1,1000)
```

all help would be great thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be with [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits) and [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). You could also use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement with an empty [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-pass_stmt) in it if don't plan on using the file and automatically want it closed:

```
from string import digits
from random import sample 

with open("".join(sample(digits, 10)), 'w'): 
    pass
```

This is equivalent to:

```
filename = "".join(sample(digits, 10)) 
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.close()
```

On consecutive calls, this generates filenames such as:

```
3672945108  6298517034
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

filename = ""
for i in range(10):
    filename += str(random.randint(0,9))

f = open(filename + ".txt", "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

`randint` takes two arguments: a lower and upper (inclusive) bound for the generated number. Your code will generate a number between 1 and 1000 (inclusive), which could be anywhere from 1 to 4 digits.

This will generate a number between 1 and 9999999999:

```
>>> n = random.randint(1, 9999999999)
```

You will then want to pad it with zero's and make it a string, in case it is less than 10 digits:

```
>>> filename = str(n).zfill(10)
```

You can then open this and write to it:

```
with open(filename + '.txt', 'w') as f:
    # do stuff
    pass
```